# NativeBase: How to set colorScheme of Input?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I want to change the colorScheme of a NativeBase Input component.

Other components, like button, slider or checkbox, have a prop "colorScheme" which, if set, changes all the associated colors of that component. Input does not have that prop.

These approaches would technically work:

- Setting colors for border, background etc. manually
  -> But it would be a lot or work and pretty ugly
- Changing the primary color in the theme
  -> But maybe I want to have two different color schemes for Input on the same page, so it would not make sense to change the theme.

So, what is the best way to easily change all the associated colors of an Input component, without setting all colors manually or changing the overall theme?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used NativeBase ( but now I'll take a look, thanks for this discovery... )

I highly recommend you to have a read at the [Customizing Components doc](https://docs.nativebase.io/customizing-components) which provide a way to do what you're looking for...

You can create a "variant" which is a predefined theme for a specific component. You have to define it in your customized theme ( If you don't use a `<NativeBaseProvider theme={theme} />` yet [check this](https://docs.nativebase.io/customizing-theme) )

```
export default function () {
  const theme = extendTheme({
    components: {
      Input: {
        variants: {
          otherColorInput: ({ colorScheme }) => {
            return {
              bg: /*otherColorToSet*/ ,
            };
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider theme={theme}>{/* components */}</NativeBaseProvider>
  );
};
```

Then you can call you new Input like this :

```
<Input variant="otherColorInput">
```

Comment: Hey Seba99, thanks for the idea! I am still wondering if there is a way to change all associated colors at once, just as in the colorScheme prop for Buttons. For example, in the filled variant of Input, there are multiple different colors present depending on if the input is hovered, focused, and different colors in the border and background and light and dark mode. Would be great if there was a way to change them all with changing one prop, instead of having to set all the shades individually. :)

Comment: I don't think it exists ... It would be the same as : "Is here a property to change color AND background-color at the same time" ^^

Comment: Yea, I agree. The funny thing is: Exactly that exists for Buttons and some other components. The the question is: Why does it exists there, but not for the Input?